# Keep GNU screen from resizing

Tags: gnu-screen

I found a few threads that dealt with screen resizing a terminal, but I'm looking to do the opposite.  I want to run a screen session with a height of 4 to limit output (why I'm doing it is complicated, which is why I'm being vague), but every time I connect to the screen it changes the height to match whatever terminal I connected from.  Is there any way to force it to keep a height of 4 rows?

Comment: Being intentionally vague is not a good way to get help. Please clearly state the original problem (you want to view a limited output of something, or perhaps you want to view two things at once) and what you've tried to fix it (putting it in `screen` and restricting the size).

Comment: The end goal is to be able to have a program that can send commands to an asynchronous bash shell and return the output, and after trying lots of other approaches I've determined that this is my best bet.  That's not the problem, however, the problem is screen resizing whenever it's attached to.

Comment: If you attach that screen session to a higher terminal, what do you want to happen? Do you want the terminal to be resized to 4 lines? Do you want screen to only use 4 lines of the terminal and leave the rest empty while scrolling those 4? Something else?